# DOMPDF on Wordpress Unable to stream pdf headers already sent

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, dompdf

I am integrating DOMPDF to my wordpress site, but I can't make it work, it always show

> Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Here is my code.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: test pdf
*/
get_header();
#
#   call sub page header
#
get_template_part('sub_page_header', 'sub_page_header_file');
?>
<?php
 require_once (get_template_directory() . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'); // or whatever your path is
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

ob_start(); 


if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h1><?php the_title();?><h1>
<?php 
the_content();
endwhile;
endif; 



    file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . 'property.html', ob_get_contents());



$ofilename=$_GET['filename'];

    $filename=(get_template_directory() . 'property.html');
    $dompdf->load_html(file_get_contents($filename));
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($ofilename.".pdf");

get_footer();?>
```

please let me know if I used the script correctly and or if there is something wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: Your usage of dompdf is passable. I'm not sure about the Wordpress part. Try moving `ob_start()` to the top of the document.

Comment: FYI, instead of jumping through so many hoops writing and reading files you could just feed dompdf the buffered content.